# how to print the disks from lsblk in GIGA

Tags: linux, filesystems, rhel, disk, lsblk

how to print the disks from lsblk in GIGA

```
lsblk -io KNAME,TYPE,SIZE,MODEL

dm-0  lvm     50G
dm-1  lvm     16G
dm-2  lvm    100G
sdb   disk   1.8T AVAGO
sdc   disk   1.8T AVAGO
sdd   disk   1.8T AVAGO
sde   disk   1.8T AVAGO
```

we need to print all disks in GIGA

we have the option -b to print in byte but we prefer in giga

Comment: What is GIGA? Do you mean gigabytes? Gigabit? Is that the same as giga?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
lsblk -b -io KNAME,TYPE,SIZE,MODEL | awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} {if (FNR>1) print $1,$2,$3/1073741824"G",$4; else print $0}'
```